# Is it possible to get the "current" version of an item through the Autodesk Data Management API

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-data-management

I'm trying to get the current version (not the latest version) from an item in the Autodesk Data Management API.

I've looked through all the endpoints and currently am using the following endpoint: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents

And I get back some information about the item I'm requesting. Of which one is the id of the item itself and one is the id of the tip of the item (which as far as I've understood is the latest version of the item).

Now it's possible through the BIM360 docs UI to change the current version of a file to one of the older versions. Now what I want is to get the id of this version when I'm requesting the information of an item. Is this at all even possbile through the Data Management API? And if so where could I get this data?

And if not through the Data Management API, is there another solution for this?
I've found that through listening to Webhooks we can get updates when those items are updated, is that the only way?

Edit for additional information:

Through the BIM 360 Document management portal I've uploaded 3 versions of a file. I've made all 3 versions the current version at different times: [BIM 360 version](https://imgur.com/RrC74Hl)

I then get the contents of the corresponding folder through the API using Postman and I get the folllowing in the response. Using this endpoint: https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data/v1/projects/:project_id/folders/:folder_id/contents

For the document I get version is 11, which is correct and what I'm expecting.
[Document version response](https://imgur.com/wSg0iDf)

But in that same response I also get the file version which is still on version 3 in the response, while I'm expecting and wanting to get back that it's version 2 as seen in the BIM 360 Document Management.
[File version response](https://imgur.com/9rjeUfq)

So the question I have is how do I get the current version of the file?

Comment: Could you please clarify what you mean by "in the same response"? From the two screenshots it looks like it's two completely separate documents inside BIM360.

Comment: @PetrBroz Yes and that's what's confusing me as well. 
For clarification, I've now again uploaded a new version of that same IFC file. And then I get the following: the document is then updated to version 12 and the file is updated to version 4, which corresponds with the version I see in the Document Management [link](https://imgur.com/NwSgLfM)
But if I then make V2 the current version again the document version will be 13 [link](https://imgur.com/UDG7rIf) while the file version will remain 4 [link](https://imgur.com/X7D7oJI). What I want is to get version 2 of the file.

Comment: I don't know what the difference is between a file and a document inside the Autodesk Document Management. I've been trying to find an explanation for that but have been unable to find it. It seems like the file is the actual IFC file itself while the document is something different. But what I want to get is the Id of the current IFC file.

Comment: @PetrBroz any information yet?

Comment: We now found that we could get the version number of the file in the versions data on the folder content endpoint. There we found in the versions object of the document there's an extension object which has data that includes the viewable name of the file and the revisionDisplayLabel of the file. That version is what we were looking for.

But the only way we found to make the direct link between the document and the file there is the sourceFileName. Is this the only link available or is it possible to linkn the document to the file through an id?

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested this real quick, and it seems that when you set an older version of an item as "current", BIM360 actually creates a new record at the top of the list of versions, and gives it the same name:

[image]

With that said, I believe the answer to your question is: the "current" version will always be the `tip` version.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Your remark made me check it again, and I see now in the code I'm working on it's using the SDK. Indeed if I go through the exact endpoint it will return the current version number. So we'll move to that.

Comment: I've checked further. What we found is that the tip version of the current document is correctly given back through the endpoint (both through SDK and v2 API). But the version of the file itself never changes from the latest version. So if I have a version 3 of a file and I make version 1 current. The document shows up as version 4 but the file still shows up as version 3. While I'm expecting document version 4 and file version 1

Comment: Are you sure this is the observed behavior? If so, that would most likely be a bug in BIM360 that I would need to report. Could you provide exact repro steps and some screenshots?

Comment: Of course, I've added additional information in my post. If there's anything else feel free to ask.